# find consecutive value in SQL

Tags: sql

I  want to find out the Consecutive Absences for the Each Student for Each Module,
here is my original result.

[image]

and  I want my Output is to add a Consecutive Absences Column and find out the consecutive Absent for Each student by  Module.

[image]

Comment: Hi @diptesh , in order to help you better, it would be great to see the code you have tried to see if you are on the right track or going off line.

Comment: Microsoft  SQl server 2012

Comment: please add your queries and data as text in your question.

Comment: Do you want a running total of consecutive absences?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Studentcode] VARCHAR(50),
    [Semester] VARCHAR(50),
    [ModuleCode] VARCHAR(50),
    [Date] VARCHAR(50),
    [WkNo] VARCHAR(50),
    [Attended] VARCHAR(50),
    [Absent] [int]
)

INSERT INTO @Tbl
SELECT [Studentcode]
      ,[Semester]
      ,[ModuleCode]
      ,[Date]
      ,[WkNo]
      ,[Attended]
      ,[Absent] FROM Attendance
ORDER BY studentcode,modulecode,date

SELECT T1.*, CASE WHEN (T1.Absent = 1 AND T2.Absent = 1)
                        AND (T1.ModuleCode = T2.ModuleCode) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CosecutiveAbsence
FROM @Tbl T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Tbl T2 
ON T1.Id = T2.Id + 1
```